# Performance issues when focusing inputs in modals?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, lag

So, I've probably stumbled upon the strangest bug/feature I've ever seen. I've developed a website which helps you read foreign books. See this book (or any book on the website, it doesn't matter): https://anylang.net/en/books/de/heaven-has-no-favorites/read.

1. Try to quickly move your mouse hovering on words/sentences, maybe click on something etc. Everything should work pretty smooth.
   On mouseover a word quickly becomes orange, on click the translation quickly appears etc.
2. Now click on the login button: [image: Login Button]

The first input should become focused.

3. Then close the modal and try the first step again. Everything becomes very laggy. The lags won't disappear no matter what you do, except:
4. Click on the page number: [image: Page Number]

Lags disappear. Completely.

The same result (lags) can be achieved by:

1. Clicking on a word inside a translation tooltip [image: Translation Click]

It has a contenteditable attribute, so the behaviour is exactly the same as in the first case.

2. Click anywhere outside the tooltip, closing it and causing the lags.
3. Lags still disappear if you click on a page number (or, probably, any input[type="text"] on the page (but not in modals))

Some things to consider:

1. The effect doesn't disappear if you lose focuse in a modal and then close it.
2. The same effect can be achieved by focusing in a modal and then manually removing a modal from dom. So javascript is not the problem.
3. If you don't remove a modal from dom but apply "display: none" to it instead, everything is ok, no lags.

My guess is that the browser gives higher priority to elements where input[type="text"] is focused and doesn't respect it when an element with the input is removed from dom. Any other ideas? This thing really boggles my mind.

Comment: I tried all of your examples and everything always works smooth for me.

Comment: @gforce301 what browser do you use? The lags are not that bad that the interface becomes unusable but they are noticeable. For example, there is a delay between hovering a word and emerging of an orange background. Did you try throttling in your browser?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit). There is no noticeable delay between  hovering a word and the emerging of an orange background. 
What would throttling do? There are no network calls happening when you apply the class `w_active` to a "hovered" word.

Comment: That's odd. Maybe your computer is too good/you not moving the mouse fast enough to cause lags/there is something wrong in my Chrome.Yes, network throttling wouldn't do much, I meant cpu throttling. Btw, I can easily reproduce the behavior on mobile Chrome but couldn't see the lags in Firefox.

Comment: @Griffin, managed to find out that removing "user-select:none" from body fixes the problem completely... It's kinda funny.

Comment: Wow interesting! I'm really curious now what was causing that. I'm glad you found your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

If you do a performance profile of your site while going through this process, you'll see that your memory allocation continues to climb as you interact with the page. You'll also notice that the more text you hover over the worse the lag eventually becomes.

This is indicative of a memory leak in your code - possibly caused by event listeners that aren't being cleaned up properly.

Without an in-depth review of your code it's unlikely anyone here is going to be able to pinpoint where the exact problem is, but hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for a hint! I'll try to check it but there are some things that don't really make sense if it's a memory leak, like why the lags disappear the moment you focus on the page number, why they appear only after focusing an input in modals AND closing the modals (because there are two completely different types of modals with different events atttached etc. and still they cause the very same lags) etc.